# How to use modernCV for creating resume in Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: mactex, moderncv, texshop

I referred multiple sources but nothing is working out. 
Used TeXShop and it did generated PDF after clicking on "Typeset".

I am missing out something , please help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Do you have a TeX distribution installed (e.g. [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/))? Did you install the document class `moderncv`? What exactly isn't working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I have MacTeX 2011 installed . How to install the document class moderncv ?
Also which software to use for installing it ? I have got TexShop , TexWorks , LatexIT installed .

Comment: I you have MacTeX, then moderncv should be installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Doncherry , Peter Breitfeld  for kind help .

Answer (score 2):

The `moderncv` package is unfortunately not very well documented. If you have TL 2011 it is installed already and you don't need to install it.  The easiest way to get going with it is to try to compile the example template file.  To do this, open a terminal window and type:

```
open -a TeXShop /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc/latex/moderncv/examples/template.tex
```

This should open the template file in TeXShop.  Before doing anything else, save this file somewhere in your own Documents folder, using the TeXShop File Menu -> Save As... item.

TeXShop's default file encoding is MacRoman, so uncomment line

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and replace `[utf8]` with `[applemac]`. If you have changed TeXShop's preferences to save files in UTF-8 format, then leave the line as it is.

Next comment out the following line:

```
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
```

(This assumes you have a photo of yourself named `picture`; since you don't, you should comment this line out.)

Once you've done this, you should be able to typeset the document.  If this fails, report back by editing your question.